# What is a good percent for the similar text function for a mini-search engine?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a mini search engine for my new poll application. When you go to http://www.pollmc.com/search.php?s=mlg (website not up yet btw) it will search for a similar poll (I have a demo one called "Mlg  Right?". It doesn't return it... But If I type in "Right" it does. It returns two polls; one called "Mlg Right?" and the other called "Cool Right?". What percent parameter is recommended for the is_similar text function? Here's my current code:

```
function  search($s, $highPriority = true) {
    $link = $this->connect();
    $results = array();
    $results_highpriority = array();
    $results_lowpriority = array();

    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM polls");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        array_push($results, $row);
    }

    foreach($results as $r) {
        if(strtolower($r['question']) == strtolower($s)) {
            array_push($results_highpriority, $r['question']);
            continue;
        }
        /*if(strlen($s) >= 3 && strpos(strtolower($r['question']), strtolower($s)) !== false) {
            array_push($results_lowpriority, $r['question']);
            continue;
        }*/
        similar_text(strtolower($r['question']), strtolower($s), $resultPercent);
        if($resultPercent >= 50) {
            array_push($results_lowpriority, $r['question']);
            continue;
        }
    }
    return $highPriority ? $results_highpriority : $results_lowpriority;
}
```

I did have - commented out - if the question from MYSQL contains the query then add it (that seemed to work) but I'm worried it will return too much when I have like 20+ polls added. Here's my SQL database: http://prntscr.com/alr811

Comment: 78.4534% really only you can decide this

Comment: ok thanks :) I'll do something like if it contains the string (if the query is >= 7 chars) or 50%. I can always change it when we get more polls.

Comment: it is best to test based on your data, and get a feel for the right value,

Comment: Let's see... `SELECT *`, no `WHERE` condition, immediately dump all results into memory... yep. Enjoy eating through all of your RAM.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks, I have since done this: `$lowestLastVote = ((round(microtime(true)*1000)) - 2629746000);

        $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM polls WHERE lastvote >= $lowestLastVote");` That way it only returns polls that have had a vote in the last month.